# Oracle tuning strategy for columns with long tails

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, statistics, optimization, query-performance

We have an Oracle 11g database, where the two biggest tables are `Customer` and `Order`. The order profile of our customers has a long tail: we have millions of customers, with most only having a small number of orders, and a core of customers who have tens or hundreds of thousands of orders*.

Most queries concern these core high-volume customers.

We have a problem with queries that include `Customer_ID` in their conditions, such as:

```
select * from Order where Order_ID in (:1, ..., :100) and Customer_ID = :101
```

Oracle seems to calculate its estimate for for `Customer_ID` cardinality as `<rows in Order>/<distinct values of Customer_Id>`. This is usually an underestimate (since most queries concern high-volume customers), which leads it to prefer plans that use indexes on `Customer_ID`**.

So far, we've been addressing this problem using plan pinning on a query-by-query basis. But low cardinality estimates on `Customer_ID` seem to be a recurring theme, and we'd like to find a way to address this more systematically.

Is there a way to handle long-tailed columns systematically?

---

*Most customers are not "popular values" for the purposes of height-balanced histograms

**For this particular query, an inlist iterator over an index unique scan on `Order_ID` is faster for high-volume `Customer_ID`s

Comment: What does "tail" mean in this context?

Comment: Could you not add a column to your table - say Valued_Customer SHORTINTEGER - use values, say, 1 - 5? That way, you can give the optimiser more of a clue.

Comment: Is upgrading to 12c an option? Top frequency histograms should be able to handle this, depending on the number of core customers.

Comment: @user1598390 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_tail

Comment: @Balazs Papp. I'd proposed 12c, for that reason, but budget and contracts and yada yada yada

Comment: @Verace Maybe, but not sure I follow. Care to elaborate?

Comment: If you assign, say, your best 100 customers a Valued_Customer value of 1 - then to get their orders, all you have to do is SELECT ... FROM Table WHERE Valued_Customer = 1; - should be fairly easy for the optimiser to get that one right (or whatever your query is, if you keep your statistics up to date). Just a thought. @user1598390 - think Pareto's law and/or the Poisson distribution.

Comment: You may try rewriting the query using `WITH` :  `WITH qr1 AS (select * from Order where Order_ID in (:1, ..., :100)) SELECT * FROM qr1 WHERE customer_id =  :101 ` - it should increase the chances optimizer chooses the plan you want.  It will be even more likely if you add `MATERIALIZE` hint  : `WITH qr1 AS (select  /*+ MATERIALIZE */ * ....`

Comment: Solutions that involve rewriting individual queries wouldn't bring us any benefit, since we can already handle specific queries using plan pinning (which is less effort, since many of the queries come from an ORM).